# Sampling from extremely skewed data in python for beginner

Tags: sampling, skewness

I have an extremely skewed data with these info:

```
Population: 25129
skewness: 3.336996478307211
kurtosis: 84.24134797666636
Min: 0.0
Mode: 5500.0
Median: 11300.0
Mean: 12226.218104649015
Max: 245540.0
```

What is the best way to determine the number of samples, and how to sample this?
And please make it simple cause i'm a beginner

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the sample?

Comment: If 25129 isn’t the number of samples, what is it?